# Icons to use in a program generating feeds for Google Search Appliance

Tags: graphics, google-search, google-search-appliance

We're developing a program that generates search feeds for Google Search Appliance. We would like to use icons that would be associated with Google Search Appliance in the program interface.

Is there a list of icons Google officially allows to use in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid not. You need to ask for Googles permission as they want to maintain the integrety of their brand

[Google Logos](http://www.google.co.uk/logos/official.html)